# Oracle INSERT with If statement for values

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to find a way to put together an INSERT which will insert a column value based on the value of another column, so for exampke

```
INSERT INTO table1
(col1a,col1b) 
SELECT 
  (dependant of the value of col2b),
  col2b
FROM table2;
```

so:

```
if col2b is 1 then col2a is A 
if col2b is 2 then col2a is B 
else col2a is C
```

Thanks in advance

KS

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the insert.

```
select
  decode(col2b, 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 'C'),
  col2b
from table2;
```

Comment: Great,thanks. I tried a CASE statement but this is a lot cleaner.

Comment: `CASE col2b WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END`

Comment: @ypercube - Thanks for that. both worked for me.